# Is it possible to TFTP files via shell script in OS X?

Tags: macos, unix, shell, tftp

I'm working on migrating my development environment from Windows to OS X and have run across a problem with TFTP. I use TFTP to upload files to an embedded network device, this is the only option to get the files on the device (no SCP support is provided).

Every time I build firmware for this device, there's a series of three files that need to be uploaded to it. On Windows I had some simple scripts that would upload all of the files I needed in one shot which makes deploying everything much simpler. These scripts were easy because the Windows TFTP client is run in one-line commands like this:

```
tftp -i <Server IP Address> PUT <Local Filename> <Server Filename>
```

It doesn't seem that there's any way to upload a file with one command like this on OS X. Instead, you have to open the tftp program and execute a series of commands that looks something like this:

```
$ tftp
tftp> connect <Server IP Address>
tftp> mode binary
tftp> put <Local Filename> <Server Filename>
tftp> quit
```

So far I have not had any luck in figuring out how to write a script to do this, although I don't have a ton of experience with Unix shell scripting. Has anyone tried to do anything similar and come up with any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use a ["here document"](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to feed commands to the `tftp` program in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

tftp <<EOF
connect <server IP Address>
mode binary
put <Local Filename 1> <Server Filename 1>
put <Local Filename 2> <Server Filename 2>
put <Local Filename 3> <Server Filename 3>
quit
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find this URL useful in shell scripting TFTP:
http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/159848-redirect-output-shell-script-tftp.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that article, I was able to get something working from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a plain text script with the commands that you'd enter at the `tftp>` prompt, and then use the unix shell's `stdin` redirect to pass the commands to the `tftp` executable.

For example, into my `/tmp/` directory, I put files `bin1` `bin2` and `bin3`.

I then used a text editor to make a file `loader.txt` with these contents:

```
binary
put bin1 
put bin2
put bin3
quit
```

Not having a TFTP server running, I used `ttcp -r -u` to open UDP port 5001, and watched to see if the file was being processed, when I executed the following in another window:

```
[Nevins-mac-mini:/tmp] nevin% tftp 127.0.0.1 5001 < loader.txt
Transfer timed out.

Transfer timed out.

Transfer timed out.

[Nevins-mac-mini:/tmp] nevin%
```

The timeouts were expected for my test case.

I verified that each file was offered in turn after the timeouts, and that they were being offered in binary, not ascii mode, so I'm confident that each line in `loader.txt` was parsed through the `tftp` binary.

I hope this helps...